# use specific ruby version in a remote ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux

I have a script. it's ran by a sensu server client. 
here is process

```
ps aux |grep sensu
sensu    18171  0.0  1.3 134716 24044 ?        Sl   12:50   0:00 /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/sensu/bin/sensu-client -b -c /etc/sensu/config.json -d /etc/sensu/conf.d -e /etc/sensu/extensions -p /var/run/sensu/sensu-client.pid -l /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log -L info
```

here is the script first lines:

```
#! /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ ruby
```

i want to know how to force the client to use a specific ruby version

tried:

```
rvm use 2.1.3
```

in the `~/.bashrc` file under root user. I dont have a `sensu` user ..

my sensu says :

`sh: 1: /etc/sensu/plugins/cpu_check.rb: Permission denied`

edit:

removed spaced in first line like so :
`#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby`
now i'm getting 
`/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require': cannot load such file -- sensu-plugin/check/cli (LoadError)`

but it's installed:

```
$: ls /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/
mixlib-cli-1.5.0  sensu-plugin-1.1.0
```

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /etc/sensu/plugins/cpu_check.rb` You probably want to remove **all** spaces in `#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby` as well.

Comment: removing the spaces helped. but now i'm getting `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- sensu-plugin/check/cli (LoadError)` . it's installed there(added the output in the question )

Comment: Do you use `rvm` on target machine? If yes, add `source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.3` just after shebang string in the executed script.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach to achieve a goal is to use script wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ] ; then
  echo "Please specify ruby version to use. Exiting..."
  exit 1
end

if [ ! -f /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-$1 ] ; then
  echo "Please specify correct ruby version to use. Exiting..."
  exit 2
end

if [ -z $2 ] ; then
  echo "Please specify ruby script to execute. Exiting..."
  exit 3
end

source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-$1
ruby "$@"
```

Usage:

```
script.sh 2.1.3 /etc/sensu/plugins/cpu_check.rb
```

Hope it helps.